# Detect keyboard events without hooks to determine user idle time

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, keyboard

I need to determine if the user is idle in this particular way.
For complicated reasons i cant use functions like GetCursorPos or any mouse related thing. Also i cant use LowLevelKeyboardProc with all the hooking and the GetMessage / TranslateMessage / DispachMessage loop running in the main function. These two options are off my choices, not for my decision.

GetLastInputInfo seemed perfect, but it cant filter only keyboard events, by default it detects both mouse and keyboard events.

Is there a simliar funcion that i can use for detecting only keyboard events?
i dont need and i dont want to know which keys are pressed, all i need to know is if the user pressed any of the keys. I will then loop and check that every half second until it returns false, then its done.
A better way would be to have in return the last time a keyboard event occurred. like GetLastInputInfo does. :(

This is hard to explain, and those are not excuses, i must avoid using hooks, and just detect if a keyboard event occurred.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why does "mouse movement" not count as user active? Surely, any user input is "activity", whether it is keyboard or mouse?

Comment: There are only two ways to monitor system wide user input: The [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) API and [Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx). Since you cannot use hooks, there's really only one option left. Unless you can talk some sense into your PM's and go for the natural solution: [GetLastInputInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302.aspx) combined with a timer. Why would actively moving a mouse count towards a user's idle time?

Comment: Yes the mouse not moving normally counts as inactivity, however another application tied to the main one generates from time to time mouse events, so i cannot detect user inactivity reliably with the mouse tracking, because mouse movement will happend programmatically. Keyboard events are still up to the human user, thats why its the only solution left for determining idle time. Also, can my application have two different windows message loops? i mean 2 threads with 2 loops, i could use another message loop to detect key presses, any key is ok.. Thanks for help

Comment: Why not just add a little bit of code to the main message loop that takes the current time for keypresses, and stores it in some place that you can check later. (Could be done with for example an atomic increment, and comparing your "last seen" value with the current value periodically).

Comment: @Mats: That code will not run when you are in a modal message loop (e.g. when displaying a modal dialog, or navigating a menu).